# Variable size multi-label candidate sampling in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, multilabel-classification

`nce_loss()` asks for a static `int` value for `num_true`. That works well for problems where we have the same amount of labels per training example and we know it in advance.

When labels have a variable shape `[None]`, and being batched and/or bucketed by bucket size with `.padded_batch()` + `.group_by_window()` it is necessary to provide a variable size `num_true` in order to accustom for all training examples. This is currently unsupported to my knowledge (correct me if I'm wrong).

In other words suppose we have either a dataset of images with an arbitrary amount of labels per each image (dog, cat, duck, etc.) or a text dataset with numerous multiple classes per sentence (class_1, class_2, ..., class_n). Classes are NOT mutually exclusive, and can vary in size between examples. 
But as the amount of possible labels can be huge 10k-100k is there a way to do a sampling loss to improve performance (in comparison with a `sigmoid_cross_entropy`)?

Is there a proper way to do this or any other workarounds?

```
nce_loss = tf.nn.nce_loss(
    weights=nce_weights,
    biases=nce_biases,
    labels=labels,
    inputs=inputs,
    num_sampled=num_sampled,
    # Something like this: 
    # `num_true=(tf.shape(labels)[-1])` instead of `num_true=const_int`
    # , would be preferable here
    num_classes=self.num_classes)
```

Comment: Hi MtDersvan, have you figured out the answer to this question?

Comment: @michal from the official page https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/nce_loss we can see the following: `Note: It would be useful to allow a variable number of target classes per example. We hope to provide this functionality in a future release. For now, if you have a variable number of target classes, you can pad them out to a constant number by either repeating them or by padding with an otherwise unused class.` In the meanwhile, I made a partially working PR to here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/14928.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues:
1) Work with NCE with different numbers of true values;
2) Classes that are NOT mutually exclusive.

To the first issue, as @michal said, there is an expectative of including this functionality in the future. I have tried almost the same thing: to use labels with `shape=(None, None)`, i.e., `true_values` dimension `None`. The `sampled_values` parameter has the same problem: `true_values` number must be a fixed integer number. The recomended work around is to use a class (`0` is the best one) representing `<PAD>` and complete the number of `true_values`. In my case, `0` is an special token that represents `<PAD>`. Part of code is here:

```
assert len(labels) <= (window_size * 2)
zeros = ((window_size * 2) - len(labels)) * [0]
labels = labels + zeros
labels.sort()
```

I sorted the label because considering another recommendation:

> Note: By default this uses a log-uniform (Zipfian) distribution for
>   sampling, so your labels must be sorted in order of decreasing
>   frequency to achieve good results.

In my case, the special tokens and more frequent words have lower indexes, otherwise, less frequent words have higher indexes. I included all label classes associated to the input at same time and completed with zero till the `true_values` number. Of course, you must ignore the `0` class at the end.